# Append Selection to Text Field as text

Tags: html, jquery, jsp, append

I'm hoping to append a selection to a text field as text.

Details:

- Two radio buttons on site
- These radio buttons have inputs of "Complete Shipment Only" or "Partial Shipments"
- Upon selecting one of these inputs, I'm wanting to append that input's text ("Complete Shipment Only" for example) to the Text Field below it.

With each selection, the previous appended text will remove itself and be added again. If not, I could end up with several lines of "Complete Shipment Only" within the text field.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="shipinfo" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <input type="radio" id="complete_shipment_only" name="shipping_preference" value="Complete Shipment Only" required <% if(shipping_preference.equals("Complete Shipment Only")) { %> checked <% } %>>
    <label for="complete_shipment_only">Complete Shipment Only</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="partial_shipments_available" name="shipping_preference" value="Partial Shipments Acceptable" <% if(shipping_preference.equals("Partial Shipments Acceptable")) { %> checked <% } %>>
    <label for="partial_shipments_available">Partial Shipments Acceptable</label><br>
</div>

<div class="shipinfo" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <label><%=eclSystem.translate(silver.getLanguage(), "Shipping Instructions")%></label><br>
    <textarea name="SHIP_INST" data-sp-id="shipInstrInput" class="inputFieldBody" style="height:55px;" rows="4" cols="54" wrap="virtual"><%=order.getShippingInfo().getInstructions()%></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event of jquery so that whenever the radio button get change then this event will get called and then you can use `.html()`to replace previous content of textarea with new content.

**Demo code**  :

```js
$("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
//getting value of radio buttonselected
  var value = $(this).val();
  //replacing previous content with new one
  $(".inputFieldBody").html(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shipinfo" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <input type="radio" id="complete_shipment_only" name="shipping_preference" value="Complete Shipment Only" checked required>
  <label for="complete_shipment_only">Complete Shipment Only</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="partial_shipments_available" name="shipping_preference" value="Partial Shipments Acceptable" <%>
  <label for="partial_shipments_available">Partial Shipments Acceptable</label><br>
</div>

<div class="shipinfo" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <label></label><br>
  <textarea name="SHIP_INST" data-sp-id="shipInstrInput" class="inputFieldBody" style="height:55px;" rows="4" cols="54" wrap="virtual">Complete Shipment Only</textarea>
</div>
```